# method that stores inputs into an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that prompts the user to input 20 numbers and stores the numbers in an alpha array. For some reason it is not working. Below is a sample of my method:

```
public  void inputArray(int a,int[]b){
    b=new int[20];
    int n=0;//int a;
    while(n<5){
        for(int i=0;i<alpha.length;i++){
            //a=window.readInt("please enter no  :");
            alpha[n]=a;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 9 questions with answers and not one of them accepted -- this will not help motivate folks to help you. You can go back through your previous questions via this link: [logic profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/689283/logic101) -- and accept answers in these previous threads.

Comment: @berry that because in my main method i have to store the contents in an array so i pass an array in as an argument in my main method

Comment: Nope, not going to work. As berry states, you'll simply create a new array in the method and it will disappear once the method is over. Instead why not have the method *return* an array of int so that the main method can used the returned array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Scanner or BufferReader as you wish, I thinks thats the simple way of doing I hope I can help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {

static int alpha[] = new int[20];
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int array[] = new int[20];
    array = inputArray(alpha);

}

public static int[] inputArray(int alpha[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        alpha[i] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(alpha[i]);
    }
    return alpha;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**I am writing a sample java code**

```
import java.util.*;
void input(int []a)
{
     Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);  
     for(int i=0;i<20;i++)?
     {
     System.out.println("Enter a number ="):
     a[i]=  sc.nextInt();
     }
}
```

This java code is not complete .You can **Google** *for How To input data from User for your specific programming language*.